# data from SQL database overlaps when outputted onto screen using pygame

Tags: python, sql

This part of the highscore page is not working properly.

What's happening, is that the data from the database is printed out onto pygame but it overlaps each other, e.g

`name1,score 100,date` is on top of `name2,score 80,date`.

This is the code, thank you.

```
def highScoreScreen():

    screen.fill(background_color)
    YChange = 50
    sql = "SELECT * FROM ScoreBoard ORDER BY Scores DESC LIMIT 10"
    c.execute(sql)
    line = "line"

    while True:
         line = c.fetchone()
        highscore_heading_message = highscore_heading_message_font.render("Welcome To The League Of The Top Players!",1,pygame.Color("red"))
        leaderboard = leaderboard_font.render(str(line[1:]),1,pygame.Color("yellow"))
        highscore_homescreen_message = homescreen_font.render("Main Menu? Press M",1,pygame.Color("green"))
        highscore_playagain_message = highscore_playagain_message_font.render("Play Again? Y/N",1,pygame.Color("green"))
        screen.blit(highscore_heading_message,(175,10))
        screen.blit(highscore_homescreen_message,(100+20,500+20))
        screen.blit(highscore_playagain_message,(500+20,500+20))
        screen.blit(leaderboard,(SCREEN_WIDTH/2 - 125,YChange))
        pygame.display.update()
```

Anybody know a fix?

Comment: `YChange` is never incremented in the loop, so it keeps putting the data in the same place

Comment: It doesn't make a difference if it's in or not, I tried it. Any other ideas or could you show me what you mean by copy and pasting please?